# Do we allow videos in questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, review

Earlier, I posted over a question that was an image. Now, one with a video.

Do we allow it? I would say no, but what do others think?

[example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/200585)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that some sites have possibility to embed videos in answers, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers/104189#104189). [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47175/stuck-on-uncharted-3-chapter-12/47445#47445) is an example of an answer with an embedded YouTube video.

Comment: Related post about answers: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7105/is-it-allowed-to-answer-a-question-with-a-youtube-video

Comment: It may be ok. Or may be not? I would say that a link to the video is ok. But otherwise... define *video*. Many of us have used gif-animations in answers. I think that's ok, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, with some very large caveats. Frequently, someone has a question about a statement in a video, or an image that's contained in a video, and it would be difficult to transcribe it properly (or with the necessary context). I'd rather have a video link than a poorly transcribed question that's missing fundamental details.

That being said, there are some general problems with this:

- The question should be specific, and (within reason) should give a specific time in the video about which the OP is asking. If people have to spend several minutes watching a video just to figure out what the question is, it's probably not a good fit here. The analogous issue for a pdf or slideshow is that there should be a specific page number given.
- To avoid link-rot and other issues that come with a non-self-contained question, there should be enough information in the question to at least roughly describe the question should the link disappear. Youtube videos do seem fairly susceptible to these issues (and in this case, as Arthur Fischer pointed out in a comment on the post, it's flagged as possible spam, so the video likely won't be around forever).

So in the end, I don't think a video link in a question is any worse than most other sorts of links (e.g. pdfs or slideshows), and that they should not be outright banned. Handling on a case-by-case basis is sufficient.

Comment: "it would be difficult to transcribe it properly (or with the necessary context)" Examples? "I don't think a video link in a question is any worse than most other sorts of links" Indeed, but this can be read in two directions, so to speak... :-)